# Arraylist, do while loop and calling a method

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist, do-while

I need to create an array list to  save the value of resistors entered by user. Then I need to ask user which type of method to calculate his answer with, then return back answer. The do while loop needs to keep asking for resistors values until user enter the number zero. The calculations have to be pulled from a class Resistance to Main.

***CLASS**********

```
import java.util.ArrayList;    

public class Resistance {

    /**
     * Holds an object type.
     */
    public int userChoice;

    ArrayList<Double> resistor = new ArrayList<Double>();

    /**
     *Chooses which process follows next.
     *@return circuitType
     */
    public final double calculateResistance() {
        if (userChoice == 1) {
            return calculateSeriesResistance();
        } else {
            return calculaParallelResistance();
        }
    }
    /**Returns object of parallel circuit.
     *
     * @return 1 / runningResistance.
     */

    public double calculaParallelResistance() {
        double runningResistance = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < resistor.lenght; ++index) {
            runningResistance = runningResistance
                    + +1 / resistor.lenght;
        }
        return 1 / runningResistance;
        }

    /**Returns object of series circuit.
     *
     * @return runningResistance.
     */
    private double calculateSeriesResistance() {
        double runningResistance = 0;    
        for (int index = 0; index < resistor.length; ++index) {
            runningResistance = runningResistance + resistor[index];
    }    
        return runningResistance;
    }
}
```

******MAIN*****************

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    /**
     * Makes a Constant.
     */
    public final static int DONE = 0;

    /**
     * Makes a Constant.
     */
    public static final int USER_CHOICE_SERIES = 1;

    /**
     * Makes a Constant.
     */
    public static final int USER_CHOICE_PARALLEL = 2;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
        Resistance myRes = new Resistance();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Display Purpose
        System.out.println("\nThis program will calculate "
                + "the resistance of a Parallel or Series "
                + "Circuit\n");   

        //Display instructions
        System.out.println("Please enter the value of your "
                + "resistors separately, when done press 0 (zero)");
        int n = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Resistor #" + ++n);
            myRes.resistor.add(keyboard.nextDouble());
        } while (myRes.resistor > 0);    

        // Ask Which Method To Use,
        do {
            System.out.println("\nEnter 1 to calculate "
                    + "a Series Circuit "
                    + "or 2 for a Parallel Circuit");
            myRes.userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

            // Ask user again in case he enters something else
            } while (myRes.userChoice != USER_CHOICE_PARALLEL
                    && myRes.userChoice != USER_CHOICE_SERIES);

        //Output the total resistance
        System.out.printf("\nThe Total Resistance is "
                + f.format(myRes.calculateResistance()));
    }    
}
```

Comment: So, do you have a question ?

Comment: So.. Here's my code. Do your thing, Stackoverflow?

Comment: Im having issues trying to create the the do while loop and the sentinel value that stops it. Also the whole adding the inputs for the arraylist, not working either

Comment: Your code doesn't it even compile. There are numerous issues, eg. ArrayList doesn't have length field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said, there are few isues with your code, let's break it down step by step.

First, ArrayList doesn't have a field called length, you want to use size() instead.

Next, your method of calculating parallel resistance is wrong. You are not iterating over your resistors, instead you're using number of resistors to calculate. The correct formula is:

1 / Rtotal = 1 / R1 + 1 / R1 + 1 / R3 + ...

Change your code to:

```
 public double calculaParallelResistance() {
    double runningResistance = 0;

    //use size() instead of length, which doesn't exist in ArrayList
    for (int index = 0; index < resistor.size(); index++) {
        //also, iterate over each resistor's value, and to get it, 
        //use...err, get() method :)
        runningResistance +=  (1 / resistor.get(index));
    }
    return 1 / runningResistance;
}
```

Your method calculateSeriesResistance() also has an issue: you can't access object by using array notation, as in resistance[index]. Use get() method, so the correct code is:

```
private double calculateSeriesResistance() {
    double runningResistance = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < resistor.size(); index++) {
        runningResistance += resistor.get(index);
    }
    return runningResistance;
}
```

Now, to the main method. Your first 'do' loop is checking against number of resistors in your ArrayList, not against 0 value entered by user. You could use while loop instead and break when 0 entered:

```
//holds current resistor's value
Double val;

while(true) {
    System.out.println("Enter Resistor #" + ++n);
    val = keyboard.nextDouble();

    //only add if higher than 0
    if (val > 0.0) {
        myRes.resistor.add(val);
    }
    //0 entered, so finish the loop
    else break;
}
```